Is MAPP Substitute gas safe for searing meat and Creme Brulee etc?
following these discussions:
Is MAPP gas safe for searing meat and Creme Brulee etc?
and
Blowtorch - hardware store vs kitchen store. Is there a difference?
I was wondering if the new MAPP gas substitute would be safe to sear food (in my case salmon), this gas consists of Propylene, Dimethyl ether and Propane. More information about the product can be found here(https://www.princessauto.com/file/general/8899320_SDS_en_01_10_04_19.pdf)
Thank you very much in advance.

MAPP gas is a generic name for a variety of gases, real MAPP gas was discontinued years ago. The question you linked to asking if MAPP is safe is the answer you need, so this is a duplicate.

Note, I've edited the original question to make it clear that MAPP nowadays means MAPP substitute.
